# Entity Framework storing image in the database

Tags: database, image, entity-framework, arrays

Im using Entity Framework and created an entity with property Image of type byte[].

I downloaded an image and saved it into a database. The image size is 345Kb.

Than I went into the SQL Management Studio and copied the text in the image column.
I copied it to a notepad and saved - the txt file size is only 43Kb.

So I wonder where all the data went?

Is there some sort of compression?